# What is the most simple T-SQL syntax to convert a datetime column into the 'MMM YYYY" format?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, datetime

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I need to add a line to my SQL query that will convert a column called StayDate into the "MMM YYYY" format.
The StayDate column is in `datetime` format (eg: 2016-06-01 00:00:00.000)

Basically, I need the output to be "Jul 2016" (from example above).

I have tried playing around with the following code:

```
Format (StayDate, "MMM DD YYYY")
```

which I converted into: `Format (StayDate, "MMM YYYY")`

But I end up with the following result: Jul YYYY

I like the simplicity of the above code a lot. Is there a workaround using the `Format`syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `format` function takes a .NET format string, so the four digit year part has to be in lowercase, like this:

```
Format(StayDate, "MMM yyyy")
```

(reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh213505(v=sql.120).aspx)

Comment: Thanks! That was brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @SYSDATE DATETIME = '2016-06-01 00:00:00.000'

SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), @SYSDATE, 106) ,8)
--OR
SELECT LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, @SYSDATE), 3) + ' ' + DATENAME(YEAR, @SYSDATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query also to achieve the same

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()) + DATENAME(YEAR, GETDATE())
```

this will return `May2016`

For a space in between

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()) +' ' + DATENAME(YEAR, GETDATE())
```

result : `May 2016`

Answer (score 0):

Using the query below will return your expected result:

```
DECLARE @StayDate AS DATETIME = '2016-06-01 00:00:00.000';
SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), @StayDate, 113), 4, 8) AS [Mon YYYY]
```